# Deploy wso2 Carbon (*.car-files) applications from command line

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We need to deploy a large amount of different carbon applications on many WSO2 ESB installations many times - release-by-release.
So for automation of this process, we want to write shell-scripts which will deploy apllications automatically.
Is there any possibility of such automation?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look to **mavent-car-deploy-plugin**, it offers you a way to deploy your car with such a command-line :

```
mvn clean deploy -Dhost=localhost -Dport=9443
```

And undeploy it :

```
mvn clean deploy -Dhost=localhost -Dport=9443 -Doperation=undeploy
```

see https://docs.wso2.com/display/DVS370/Deploying+a+CAR+File+with+the+Maven+Plug-In

Answer (score 1):

copy your car file in the repository/deployment/server/carbonapps sub-directory of your ESB server. Il will be automatically deplyoyed.
To undeploy the App just delete the file.